# How to extract an element from within a WebElement

Tags: xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to extract multiple WebElements from within a WebElement? For instance I have the following:

```
        String filterRowXpath = "(//div[@id=\"tabItemFilters\"]//div[@id=\"RowExpGridWidgetGridPanel\"]//div[@class=\"x-grid3-body\"]//tbody)";
    List<WebElement> filterRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(filterRowXpath));
```

I end up with a WebElement that contains 5 elements itself, is there a way for me to reference elements 2 and 3 for instance?

Comment: Please post a snippet of the XML you're targeting, and what output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like :

```
<tbody>
<webelement>1<webelement/>
<webelement>2<webelement/>
<webelement>3<webelement/>
</tbody>
```

And you want 2 or 3, you can add [2] or [3] which is equivalent to `[position()=2]` or `[position()=3]`.

So for your XPath it would be ..`//tbody[position()=2 or position()=3]` if you're looking for either of those positions. Note that you cannot use shorthand as in the previous statement if you are searching for multiple positions.

**UPDATE:**

```
filterRowXpath= "(((//div[@id=\"tabItemFilters\"]//div[@id=\"RowExpGridWidgetGridPanel\"]//div[@class=\"x-grid3-body\"]//tbody)[" + i + "])//td)[position()=2 or position()=3]
```

This will give you two node results back, instead of executing separate xpaths for each one.

```
List<WebElement> filterRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(filterRowXpath));
```

Then apply your condition to the WebElements. You were almost there in the snippet posted in your original question.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is evaluate positions 2 and 3 for a particular condition. I would need a way to get both with the same Xpath, and to make matters a little worst I have multiple rows so I have to search each row for both conditions. That's why I got a list of WebElements so I could then iterate through each element but it didn't work out so well since I couldn't access individual elements within the row with Selenium, at least I don't think I can. 

I came up with a different solution but there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm adding my solution as an answer but I welcome any better/more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: Ok, so one way you can make it more efficient is by combining your first two xpaths into one, as shown in the last part of my answer, I'll update this as well.

Comment: I'm not near my computer to test at the moment but assuming your suggestion works would wach of the WebElement filterRows contain the two nodes? If so, how would I access each of the nodes?

Comment: The list will contain 2 nodes, then loop through/iterate and apply your conditions.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding here.. findElements will return a whole of elements in a single list object, now within that list object or row I need to access the 2 nodes, could you give me an example of how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
    String ipFromValueXpath; 
    String ipToValueXpath;

    for(int i=1; i<=filterRows.size(); ++i) {
        ipFromValueXpath = "(((//div[@id=\"tabItemFilters\"]//div[@id=\"RowExpGridWidgetGridPanel\"]//div[@class=\"x-grid3-body\"]//tbody)[" + i + "])//td)[2]";
        ipToValueXpath = "(((//div[@id=\"tabItemFilters\"]//div[@id=\"RowExpGridWidgetGridPanel\"]//div[@class=\"x-grid3-body\"]//tbody)[" + i + "])//td)[3]";

        WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(ipFromValueXpath));
        String ipFromValue = e1.getText();

        WebElement e2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(ipToValueXpath));
        String ipToValue = e2.getText();

        if(ipFromValue.equals(ipFrom) && ipToValue.equals(ipTo)) {
            e1.click();
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(deleteFilterButtonXpath));
            element.click();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            AdminFunctions.apply();
            return;
        }

    }
```

I had to get the Xpath for each element then iterate through each row to find a match. I don't think it's the most efficient way to do it though.